# How To Get Data Ordered From Firebase REST API

Tags: firebase, rest, api, firebase-realtime-database, godot

I have a Firebase database of players scores .

Ex .

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "2SjkDBRLpNNUrWQzkKZxGaaaEIT2",
      "fields": {
        "PlayerName": {
          "stringValue": "Player1"
        },
        "score": {
          "integerValue": "51"
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2020-04-08T16:57:22.016282Z",
      "updateTime": "2020-04-08T16:57:22.016282Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "OkLV0Od4UBQbJVADOJkCM0l2ayM2",
      "fields": {
        "score": {
          "integerValue": "119"
        },
        "PlayerName": {
          "stringValue": "Player2"
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2020-04-08T16:03:06.417921Z",
      "updateTime": "2020-04-08T16:03:06.417921Z"
    }]
}
```

i am using the **REST API** to get this data in my game **(Godot Engine)**, by sending an **http request** to 
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{ProjectId}/databases/(default)/documents/scores`

When sending the request the response i get is only random 20 documents .

MY QUESTION IS :
How can i get the First **20 Players** (documents) ordered by the "score"  "IntegerValue" **even** if the data is **more** than 1000 documents.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference("<your_main_node>");
Query query = ref.child("documents").child("score").orderByChild("integerValue").limit(20);
```

Comment: i am using only REST API

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.